# ImageMagick, Increase transparent area around a png image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a png image like this

Current

[image]

and I need to, increase the transparent area of the image by 20px on each side.
Not sure, but wondering if there is a ImageMagick's command to do that.

Again, don't want to scale the image, just need to add an additional 20px transparent area on each side.

Expected: Area b/w green and blue is the added 20px around each side

[image]

Need a terminal command to do that.

**Note: Ignore the border color, that is just to demonstrate the requirement.**

Comment: I would try adding a 20px transparent border

Comment: right, but I need a terminal command to do that.

Comment: convert input.png -bodercolor transparent -border 20x20 output.png

Comment: Worked, thanks, just one typo "bordercolor"
`convert -bordercolor transparent -border 20 before.png beforex20.png`